# Website Form do not carry any value when .htaccess File Extension Remover Code is Used

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this code in HTACCESS file and it works fine as it remove .php file extension.It also allows page to load without extension.

```
# For security reasons, Option followsymlinks cannot be overridden.
#Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

It works fine.The issue is when i use this code

```
<form action="test.php" method="post" id="myform" name="myform">
<input type="text"  name="username">
<input type="submit" value="login">
</form>
```

On test.php `echo $_REQUEST['username'];` is empty/null.

I tried to remove .php from form action then it worked.But i can not remove .php from all files used in website.

For Duplicate markers:I read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711870/htaccess-file-extension-remover-code-breaks-website-form) but my question is different.With me,form submites but carrying no values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert this rule just below `RewriteBase` line to avoid redirecting POST requests:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

Comment: I do not want to waste time in marking this as answer..save my time..thanks