# .htaccess to hide php extension preventing POST

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've been trying to hide the php extensions for my site. And I've been able to pull together a few Stackoverflow answers to do just that. However, I just have one last issue where when I POST, the resulting page is showing the .php extension. Can anybody help me on what I need to tweak with my htaccess file to not show .php completely?

```
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ http://www.example.com/folder/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ http://www.example.com/folder/$1 [R=301,L]

# Resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

Here are the two resources I used from Stackoverflow:
[How to hide .php extension in .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371634/hide-php-extension-htaccess)
[Website Form do not carry any value when .htaccess File Extension Remover Code is Used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24138379/website-form-do-not-carry-any-value-when-htaccess-file-extension-remover-code-i)

Comment: WHats the url of result page having `.php` extension can you show a sample

Answer (score 1):

Remove this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

It says:

> Dear mod-rewrite
>
> If the request method is `POST`, whatever the url is, would you please leave it
>   unchanged without doing any rewriting? And would you please not apply any other rules?
>
> Sincerely yours,
>
> etc. etc.

Comment: That causes the issue I was having before, where when I POST it was not redirecting me to the resulting page. After I added that, I was redirected but with ".php" extension showing.

Comment: Ha, is that right? Let me think about this. And maybe someone else will have a better idea. :)